# how to view memory regions in a core-dump using lldb?

Tags: lldb

How can I view the memory regions (gdb equivalent of 'i proc maps') in a core-dump using lldb?
I want to see where the stack, heap, and modules are located.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The command "memory region" will tell you the region for a given address, but doesn't dump all regions.  There's a SB API to get the region list for a process (SBProcess.GetMemoryRegions) so you could easily write a little command to print the regions.  It doesn't look like on OS X there's much useful information there, just extents and permissions for stack & heap, however.